# How do I display an alternative charchter in a Doc that is pulling data from a sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have created an HTML form (not a Google Form) that populates a Google Sheet. The form has both text inpt and checkboxes (multiples of each.)  On the Google Sheet, if a checkbox is checked on the form, it populates the cell in the Sheet as "On".

I am looking to create a Doc using markers to pull the data from the sheet to a printable form, but I need to have a checkmark present instead of the cell data.  I suppose I could create additional columns and use an IF array for each instance of the "On" to create a checkmark in the adjacent column to display a checkmark, but I'm sure there's an easier way to do it with a script in the Doc but I have no idea where to start.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode char#9745 is a "check box check". The formula `=CHAR(9745)` will produce the checkbox check (as shown in the sample below). But `CHAR()` is not available in a script.

To convert a Unicode value use `String.fromCharCode(9745)`.

This script is an example of testing for a value of "ON" and, if true, creating a new variable with a value of the checkboxcheck. In this script the variable is then pasted into cell A2 for demonstration purposes.

---

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")

  var cellA1 = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()

  if (cellA1 === "ON"){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: it is ON")
    var chkbox = String.fromCharCode(9745)
    sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(chkbox)
  }
  else{
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: it is NOT on")
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

[image: snapshot]